# Any mesh smoothing algorithm that preserves vertex positions?

Tags: mesh, vertices, subdivision-surface, smooth, interpolation

Is there a mesh smoothing algorithm that adds detail (like subdivision surface) but preserves (at least more-less) positions of original vertices (unlike subdivision surface)? Preferably one available for Blender, but not necessarily. Maybe Meshlab or Meshmixer have that kind of toys, or maybe that's even doable with geonodes.

EDIT:

My rough idea for that is to apply a simple subdivision (not catmull-clark)
to a mesh, then pin positions of original vertices and kind of blur coordinates of the newly created vertices, to achieve smooth sine-like transitions between original vertices. That would allow preserving silhouette of the original mesh while increasing detail.

I tried catmull-clark subdivision + shrinkwrap over the original mesh, but it doesn't work.

It could be useful for attempts of undoing mesh decimations or generating smooth, interpolated terrain mesh from height points. I know there are 3D terrain generators that use such algorithms. One of them, for instance, is TopoShaper, a plugin for SketchUp.

See here, in 1:25 - 1:40:

youtube.com/watch?v=bc1prnzkAXs

I came across an article that offers an idea, not sure if relevant, cause it's not available for free, so I couldn't read it, just the abstract:
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/1467-8659.00334
Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: In case you can’t see my comment on the deleted answer, I can understand why the thing I suggested didn’t work. Bother

Comment: @TheLabCat Your approach is doable if you do it in GN and use index to identify created verts.  But, I don't think it'll do anything useful-- simply subdivided positions are already perfectly smooth, and smoothing CC will give you volume loss while just moving verts to simple subdivided positions-- planar with neighbors.  As for this question, it doesn't make sense to me to ask, "How to smooth while keeping spikes?"  Smoothing means removing spikes.  "How to smooth only spikes of a certain frequency?" is answerable; it is Laplacian smooth.

Comment: Right, I may have put it not quite right. What I mean is a process that will densify the geometry by subdividing faces (it can be simple subdivision algorithm, which won't alter the silhouette at all), then pin (lock) the positions of original verts, then evenly apply something like smoothing brush in sculpt mode. My aim is not to keep spikes sharp, but to keep positions of original verts while obtaining a smooth mesh of higher density. Think about land survey data - you'll want to keep exact altitudes of measured spots, but you also want to get nice smooth interpolated mesh out of it.

Comment: I'm thinking about something like shown here, in 1:25 - 1:40 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bc1prnzkAXs

Comment: Btw. what do you mean by "smoothing CC"?

Comment: Smoothing Catmull-Clark subdivision, as opposed to smoothing simple subdivision.

Comment: Nathan, I edited my question, so now your replies may seem less relevant to the new readers, but you actually helped me realize that I explained my wish quite poorly at first, so I did a better job now :D Hopefully someone will still chime in.